# JSF Progressbar - Server-side process

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, progress-bar

How can I show the server's progress on a Facelet?
Do I need to write a **Servlet**? Or is it possible via `ApplicationScoped` Beans?

I want to update the indicator (the progress bar) in an Ajax fashion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what things you would like to show the progress of. Basically you put a progress bar component on your Facelet (e.g. http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/progressBar.jsf) and value bind it to a bean that is able to provide the progress information.

How to obtain said progress is another question entirely and is outside the direct realm of JSF. For instance if the back ground progress was a Quartz job, your bean might remember its job ID and look it up with the Quartz scheduler every time the progress bar sends a poll request. The code running inside the Quartz job then needs to calculate how far it is in the overall process.

With Servlet 3.0 and CDI's event bus it would also be possible to take advantage of reverse AJAX / comet and let the progress bar wait for update events instead of letting the progress bar do polling. In that case, your back ground job would have to periodically publish update events. This would be more efficient, but is still relatively new and not always supported right out of the box.

Comment: I have done the process and I can get it's progress value, so I think the first solution is enough for me, but the second solution is very nice too and I may try it someday.